# Paypal button did not work on https

Tags: javascript, paypal, express-checkout

My paypal button (actually is express checkout) won't work on https, I realized this when I access my lived app with https.

Not sure it is my https blocking this script.

```
  <script src="https://www.paypalobjects.com/api/checkout.js" data-version-4></script>
```

I have no problem seeing that button being load on localhost (development environment). But in production with https, I got this error

```
ppxo_xc_ppbutton_error Object 

 Error: Document is ready and element #paypal-button does not exist
```

I'm using angular, this block of code is within my controller

```
    paypal.Button.render({

      env: 'production', // Optional: specify 'sandbox' environment

      payment: function() {

          var env    = this.props.env;
          var client = this.props.client;

          return paypal.rest.payment.create(env, client, {
              transactions: [{
                  amount: { total: 5 , currency: 'USD' },
                  item_list: {
                  items: [{
                      "name": "profile",
                      "price": "5",
                      "currency": "USD"
                  }]
                }
              }],
              redirect_urls: {
                "return_url": $location.absUrl(),
                "cancel_url": $location.absUrl()
              }
          });
      },

      commit: true, // Optional: show a 'Pay Now' button in the checkout flow

      onAuthorize: function(data, actions) {

          return actions.payment.execute().then(function() {

              actions.payment.get().then(function(data){

                if(data.state === 'approved'){
                  $http.post('/paid',{qty:$scope.number_of_uses,user_email:user_email})
                  .then(function(response){

                      $scope.done = true;

                  });
                }

              });

          });
      }

  }, '#paypal-button');
```

I repeat, it's working fine in localhost but not in https (production).

Comment: Please provide a [mcve].

Comment: element `#paypal-button` does not exist

Comment: @MackieeE No, it does. It just did not work in https, it worked well when I'm in development URL which is http://localhost:3000

Comment: @RandoHinn it's not about the code I think, anyway I added partially my code.

Answer (score 0):

The button actually sets up an angular component for you:

https://github.com/paypal/paypal-checkout/blob/master/docs/frameworks.md#angularjs-element

May be advisable to use this. I suspect if you try to render directly in an angular controller, it may have not rendered the container element yet, hence your error.

Comment: No idea, unless you can provide an example of the angular code you're using and perhaps a demo page I can try.

Comment: I found out the script load before my angular template finish rendering. I debug using network tool of chrome, i use slower connection. i put a timeout of paypal's function and now it's working.